# Installed fonts not showing up in ubuntu terminal

Tags: fonts

i have installed fonts that i can see using fc-list but it does not appear as an option to select this font in ubuntu terminal preferences.

```
/home/kay/.local/share/fonts/iosevka-custom/ttf/iosevka-custom-regular.ttf: Iosevka Custom:style=Regular
```

ubuntu 20.04 -
5.11.0-36-generic

Comment: Is that a monospace font? `gnome-terminal` only makes monospace fonts selectable AFAIK.